# How to insert, update rows in database from Spark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I made Dataframe in Spark.

The Dataframe has new rows and the same rows by key columns that table of database has.

I need insert new rows and update existing rows.

For example:

Dataframe:

| Key1 | Key2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | new value |
| 2 | 22 | value |

Table in database:

| Key1 | Key2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | old value |
| 3 | 33 | other value |

I need to write my DataFrame into database and get next result:

Table in database:

| Key1 | Key2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | **new value** |
| **2** | **22** | **value** |
| 3 | 33 | other value |

Where

(1, 11) was updated

(2, 22) was inserted

(3, 33) wasn't changed

I guess there are two possible solutions:

1. Merge data in new DataFrame and fully rewrite table in Database
2. Or insert/update data from DataFrame directly into Database

I have no idea how to proceed with this. Which instruments to use for this task? Help me to understand in which direction to move.

Comment: I guess that I just need to use: `DataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.overwrite)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no SaveMode.Upsert feature in spark currently.
(SaveMode.overwrite) will overwrite your existing table with your Dataframe.

You can repartition the dataframe and create a JDBC/POSTGRESS connection per partition and perform batch update for upsert.

https://medium.com/@thomaspt748/how-to-upsert-data-into-relational-database-using-spark-7d2d92e05bb9

Comment: Unfortunate is not the correct way of looking at. Spark is for other things.

Comment: @thebluephantom Can update the external dataset (postgres) record from the spark?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach to insert or update records in the database from Spark Dataframe is to first write the dataframe to a csv file.

Next, the csv can be streamed (to prevent out-of-memory error if the csv file is too large). Read each row in csv file and update the corresponding row in database which matches the primary key.

But this approach could cause issues if the data in the database has been modified by an external application in the meantime (i.e., in the time it took us to write to the database from the csv). This can be mitigated by using event sourcing pattern. In this approach, we don't update/modify the row once it is inserted. We just add a new event every time a column has been modified. We combine/aggregate all events from the past to arrive at the current values in the row.